# What is the proper terminology for "hoarding" type paradox (but not extreme)?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Feel free to edit my title -- I'm not exactly how to sum it up in one sentence, THUS my question here:

Is there a name or specific terminology related to the somewhat paradoxical situation in this example:

There is an almost-empty jar of imported candy in my kitchen. I have slowed (rather, ceased) consumption of this candy, because I fear I'll run out.

Obviously, logic says that not consuming and not being ABLE to consume are pretty much the same.

Is there a name for what's happening in my brain, concerning this candy, or is that behavior defined by some broader term?

I'm certain this has been researched, but I'm not sure how to find it.